# Django grappeli - include link to custom admin page in side-panel dropdown-menu

Tags: django, mezzanine, django-grappelli

I use Django 1.7 with Mezzaine.

I create a custom admin page according to:
[Django - custom admin page not releated to a model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26325506/3960850)

I would like to include link to that page to grappeli side-panel dropdown-menu. Is there a way how to achieve that without touching the side-panel template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the `ADMIN_MENU_ORDER`-constant in your `settings.py`.

It probably looks like this:

```
# ADMIN_MENU_ORDER = (
#     ("Content", ("pages.Page", "blog.BlogPost",
#        "generic.ThreadedComment", ("Media Library", "fb_browse"),)),
#     ("Site", ("sites.Site", "redirects.Redirect", "conf.Setting")),
#     ("Users", ("auth.User", "auth.Group",)),
# )
```

You have to uncomment these lines first. Assuming your recently created admin page is called `verycustom.SuchCustomPage`, you have to insert it at the desired position in your menu-list.

Example:

```
ADMIN_MENU_ORDER = (
     ("Content", ("pages.Page", "verycustom.SuchCustomPage", "blog.BlogPost",
        "generic.ThreadedComment", ("Media Library", "fb_browse"))),
     ("Site", ("sites.Site", "redirects.Redirect", "conf.Setting")),
     ("Users", ("auth.User", "auth.Group",)),
)
```

Edit: You'll find a detailed explaination in the official [documentation](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/admin-customization.html).